# PyMySQL: I am getting an error importing PyMySQL module in python

Tags: python, server, pymysql

How can i install pymysql using my server.

```
-bash-3.2$ python  script.py 'US'
```

> Trace back (most recent call last):
>
> File "script.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> import pymysql
> ```
>
> Import Error: No module named pymysql

Comment: What version of python do you have installed?

Comment: Did you install pymysql with pip?

Answer (score 1):

If pip is available on your shell you can simply do:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

One time should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Install the module to your default python installation

```
[root@server] python -m pip install PyMySQL
```

Execute your script

```
[root@server] python script.py 'US'
```